# Linq to Entities - Query to check for match on "n" number of characters from input

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, linq-to-entities

I want to bring back a set of results based on the characters typed in by a user.

I've created the following query which does what I want inside of LINQpad4

**LinqPad**

```
var PostCodes = (from OA in OrganisationAddresses
               join OV in OpportunityVersions on OA.ID equals OV.LocationID
               where OA.CurrentVersion.PostCode.Contains("LH") 
               select OV.ID).ToList();

PostCodes.Dump();
```

The user enters the string of "LH" and I get 13 results back

Now when I place a very similar query into my production environment, if I type in "LH" I get zero results. it only returns matches when the full string is entered such as "LH1 1HP"

**Production**

```
Builder = Builder.And(o => 
(from OA in Context.OrganisationAddresses
 join OV in Context.OpportunityVersions on OA.ID equals OV.LocationID
 where Options.PostCode.Contains(OA.CurrentVersion.PostCode) 
 && OV.ID == o.CurrentVersionID select OV.ID).Any());
```

I am using SQLServer2012 and LINQ to Entities. I would like to know what could be causing this and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: How is your LinqPad query related to the query in your Production system? They look completely disparate!

Comment: Ahh, yes my mistake, I've edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you swapped some code by mistake

```
Builder = Builder.And(o => 
(from OA in Context.OrganisationAddresses
 join OV in Context.OpportunityVersions on OA.ID equals OV.LocationID
 where OA.CurrentVersion.PostCode.Contains(Options.PostCode) // fix in this string
 && OV.ID == o.CurrentVersionID select OV.ID).Any());
```

And also you have additional condition in prod:

```
&& OV.ID == o.CurrentVersionID
```

Comment: Thanks. The last part of the condition is needed though as I am checking against an anonymous type